# How to write DAO for JPA having One entity with One to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, dao

I am writing DAO for eg I have Employee and Address entity
Where One employee can have multiple address.

Now my EmployeeDao have CRUD operation, I have a getEmployeeById method which takes String as input and returns EmployeeDto ( note Dto ), now in some case I need only EmployeeDto, and in some I need EmployeeDto with AddressDto as well.

My question is should I write AddreddEntity to AddressDto conversion in EmployeeDao's getEmployeeById method, is this the right way ? is there better approach to solve such kind of real world problem?

I am using JPA

Answer (score 1):

I would say there should be service layer which will process your JPA entity and and provide you the Dto.

A DAO should provide access to a single related source of data and its methods should reflect the database somewhat closely.

A Service can provide a higher level interface to process your business objects, it can interact with different databases (and different DAO's). It may have certain business logic that converts several data objects into a single, robust, business object.

Comment: In case of JPA then there no use of DAO ?

Comment: In case of JPA also there should be DAO. But It will only keep the database interaction part, rest of the processing can be done at service layer based on your requirement. give it a thought.